# Internet Explorer 11 cannot connect to any website

Tags: internet-explorer-11

As of this morning today my Internet Explorer can no longer connect to the internet. It just gets stuck in "waiting for X website" such as "waiting for google.com". It cannot connect to any website.

My internet is working fine on my other computer, on my phone and on this computer if I use Chrome or Firefox. It doesn't work only on Internet Explorer.
I do not use Internet Explorer. I do not use it ever. The problem is my League of Legends game cannot connect to the servers because if Inter Explorer is not working then the game cannot connect.

So far I have tried reset advanced settings then reset. I tried enable and disable it in turn on/off windows features. I tried disabling extensions, I tried deleting browsing history etc. Nothing works.

It worked fine yesterday.

Windows updates history states that I updated my Windows defender, some regular windows 8.1 updates, security update for flash ie 11 and cumulative security update for ie 11. This was done 4 days ago.

I tried disabling Windows defender and my firewall. Nothing changes.

Comment: Roll it back? System restore exists for a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Look to see if you have setup a proxy on internet explorer, under tools, internet options, connections tab, LAN setings, "user Proxy server for your LAN".